# Stop a posted form from re-posting

Tags: php, html, wordpress, post

I need to be able to stop a page from posting once the data in it has been submitted. For example I could have this form:

```
<form action='#' method='post'>
    <input type='text' name='name' />
    <input type='submit' name='submit' />
</form>
```

Then catch the post like this:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    echo "Hello " .  $_POST['name'];
}
?>
```

But when the page refreshes it will preform the same action time and again until either the user leaves the page or does a full refresh on the page. This is causing me a huge issue as it is imperative I am able to stop the post from preforming once it has been done.

I have tried using a meta tag (`<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5">`) to refresh the page, but this caused an issue as every few seconds it would do it and the page data was lost, I have tried to unset the post variable (`unset($_POST['submit']);` and `unset($_POST);`), but this did not work, I cannot use header("Location: ...") as I am using WordPress and thus headers are always sent by the system.

So I ask this of the community we have: How can I stop the post from re-submitting the data?

***EDIT***

What I am now doing:

```
<?php
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
    session_start();
}
$token = rand();
if ($_POST) {
    if (isset($_SERVER['token'])) {
        if($_POST['token'] == $_SESSION['token']){
            $continue = FALSE;
        }
        else {
            $continue = TRUE;
        }
    }
    else {
        $_SERVER['token'] = $_POST['token'];
        $continue = TRUE;
    }

    if ($continue === TRUE) {
        if (isset($_POST['update'])) {
            //Do update code
        }
        if (isset($_POST['win'])) {
            //Do win code
        }
        if (isset($_POST['credit'])) {
            //do credit code
        }
    }
}
```

Form:

```
<form method="post" action="#">
    <select name="select">
        <option value="false" <? if ($results->data[$i]['marked'] == "false") { echo "selected"; } ?>>No Attention</option>
        <option value="true" <? if ($results->data[$i]['marked'] == "true") { echo "selected"; } ?>>Needs attention</option>
    </select>
    <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo $token; ?>" />

    <input type="hidden" name="betid" value="<? echo $results->data[$i]['bet_id']; ?>" />
    <input name="update" id="" class="btn btn-default" value="Update" type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Yeah, was meant to just be a pipe, my bad

Comment: You can generate a token on before submitting and then send that token along with the form, then once the form has been submitted store the token into a session, then check if the session token is equal the POST/get token, if it is, don't execute the submit, if it isn't then execute. (If the user wants to submit new data a new token will be generated in the form, but a refresh will keep the old token.)

Comment: @Epodax, so do `if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { if (!isset($_SESSION['token'])) { /*do action*/ $_SESSION['token'] = new_token(); } }`?

Comment: I'll post an' answer, it'll be easier to explain.

Comment: Or do `$posttoken = new_token();` so it lasts for the pages lifetime only?

Comment: @Epodax, thank you, that would be appreciated

Comment: Best way is to put the error/success message in a `session` bag, do a `header('Location ....');` to the confirm/error page and display the flash messages there.

Comment: @DarkBee, as stated in the question, I cannot do a `header("Location: ...");` because of wordpress.

Comment: You can bypass this with `ob_end_clean()` to supress output

Comment: @DarkBee, with `ob_end_clean()` : Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at `file`) in `file` on line number

Comment: You need to start the output buffering to enable this though... `ob_start()` at first line

Comment: @DarkBee, same error, just moved a line down

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
<?php
$token = rand(); //Or how ever you want to generate a random token
?>

<form action='#' method='post'>
    <input type='text' name='name' />
    <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo $token; ?>" />
    <input type='submit' name='submit' />
</form>
```

Then catching the post

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
   if (isset($_SESSION['token']) ) {
       if($_POST['token'] == $_SESSION['token']){
           $continue = FALSE;
       }else{
           $continue = TRUE;
       }
   }else{
     $continue = TRUE;
   }

  if($continue === TRUE){
     $_SESSION['token'] = $_POST['token'];
     //DO SOMETHING
  }
}
?>
```

It can properly be made smaller / more compact but you should get the idea behind the code, this way if a user who has already submitted data can submit new data if he access the form a new, but if the page refreshes the data won't be procesed again

Of course you have to be sure that SESSION is startet

Comment: This hasn't worked for me, I have added an edit with my actual code stripped of major details, could you tell me if I am doing anything wrong?

Comment: Where is the form? The token you generate with rand should be submitted with the form - also you should put the `$_SESSION['token'] = $_POST['token']` in the `if($continue === true)` clause

Comment: @SamSwift see my comment above.

Comment: I have added the form and updated the PHP in the code

Comment: @SamSwift Remove the `$token = rand();` that you have below the `if($_POST)` clause, also, remember that you need to generate the $token BEFORE the form so that when you echo the token into the hidden field it won't give you a "undefined variable" error.

Comment: The `$token = rand()` isn't below the `if ($_POST)` clause, it comes before it and after the `if (!isset($_SESSION))` clause

Comment: @samswift thats the one i ment, it should be above the form

Comment: The php functionality is held at the top of the page, the 5th line has the rand where the form is around line 100

Comment: Ok, but you also have wrote $_SERVER instead of $_SESSION

Comment: That was it! Stupid mistake in my code from what you had given. Apologies for that and thank you very much

Comment: No problem, also i would still move the .  $_SESSION['token'] = $_POST['token']; into the if($continue === true) clause, at the start of it like in my example, don't forget to mark my answer/question as solved

Comment: I have moved this, I must have forgotten to update it in my code

Answer (score 2):

This is a perfect question to link one of my favourite answers on Stackexchange:
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/46716/what-technical-details-should-a-programmer-of-a-web-application-consider-before

This answer also says:

> [Redirect after a POST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) if that POST was successful, to prevent a
>   refresh from submitting again.

I do recommend you to click on the link.

So basically to redirect after a post has been submitted. Instead of posting to the page you go to now when you post information, you post to a redirect that redirects to the page you want to go. This will make sure when you refresh, it wont post the information again.