# Stop a post from resending information

Tags: php, html, post

I have a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30347027/stop-a-posted-form-from-re-posting) asked prior to this one where I asked for a way to stop a post from being resent on submit.

The community gave me this function:

```
function cansend($token) {
    if(isset($_SESSION['token'])) {        
        if ($token == $_SESSION['token']){
            $continue = false;
        }
        else {
            $continue = true;
        }
    }
    else {
        $_SESSION['token'] = $token;
        $continue = true;
    }
    return $continue;
}
```

This was perfect and did what I needed it to, however, this always returns true for some reason now and does not stop the method being posted again.

The form I have is along these lines :

```
<?php
$token = rand();

if ($_POST) {
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        if (cansend($_POST['token'])) {
            print $_POST['textinput'];
        }
    }
}
?>

<form action="#" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo $token ?>" />
    <input type="text" name="textinput" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

What do I need to change and where to make this work again?

***EDIT***

Actual code:

```
$_SLIP = new BettingSlip();
if ($_SLIP->CanSend($_POST['token'])) {
    if (isset($_POST['creditAcc'])) {
        $_SLIP->SetUserBalance($_POST['id'], $_POST['amount'], 'in');
    }
    if (isset($_POST['setLimit'])) {
        $_USERMAN->setlimit($_POST['id'], $_POST['limit']);
    }
}
else {
    echo "Cannot resend the same information twice";
}
```

Comment: I would remove the `if ($_POST)` wrapper. It's just adding needless complexity. `if (isset($_POST['submit']))` is more than sufficient

Comment: Did you break the code I made you? :(

Comment: @Epodax, I didn't mean to :'(

Comment: It looks like `$token` is generated every time the page is loaded

Comment: ah yes, you are sending the $token value to the function instead of the $_POST['token'] value.

Comment: @Machavity, `$token` is generated every time, but the function that @Epodax provided stores it in the session and the post holds the old value from the last loaded page after resubmission

Comment: I'll add my actual code to the bottom of the question, the `cansend($token)` in the `if ($_POST) { ... }` was a typo

Comment: I'm a little bit confused. The code, as I read it, says that if there isn't a token in the session or if the token in the session does not match the passed token, it let's you through. If the token DOES match the session token, it's rejected. Should that not be the other way around on that last part? i.e. should `if ($token == $_SESSION['token']){` not be `if ($token !== $_SESSION['token']){`

Comment: No, it's to avoid the form being submitted twice.

Comment: @KevinNagurski, Epodax is right, I want to say { if the session token is the same as the form token, reject the calling object and pass back false, otherwise if it is set and does not equal, it allows the post, if the session token is not set, then set it to equal the post token and allow the post to occur }

Comment: @Epodax oh right, get ya now, good idea.

Comment: You do have the session startet right?

Comment: The session is started, yes

Comment: Could you try and throw in a die(); in each if and else clause in the canSend function, and add a identifier ofc so we know which die was executed? so we can see where it fails?

Comment: The die made the script stop where the `$_SESSION['token'] = $token;`

Comment: Also on resubmitting?

Comment: Yes, I dumped the variables for both the POST and SESSION tokens and they matched perfectly, but it didn't enter the isset($_SESSION['token']) clause for some reason...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79011/discussion-between-epodax-and-sam-swift).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to create a random value when the page is started and to set it to a session and a hidden form like you're doing now.

```
<?php 
$_SESSION['token'] = $somerandom; //give the session token a random value
$token = $somerandom; //give the same value to the variable token
?>
```

Next you echo the token into a hidden form like you're doing already

```
<form action="#" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo $token ?>" />
    <input type="text" name="textinput" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

Than in the processing form all you have to do is check if the $_SESSION token is the same as the $_POST token.

```
if($_POST['token'] == $_SESSION['token']){
    //Do something
}
```

Everytime you open the main page it will change the session variable. So the post value which still contains the old token will no longer match the newer Session token.

This works simpler in my eyes and doesn't require you to create a function for it.

Comment: I want the function as I have many pages I want to stop from resending, also the sessiontoken and posttoken will always be the same this way as they are both set to $somerandom, therefore, it will NEVER post the information and that is not what I want from it, I want it to only send one of the posts and not the subsequent resubmissions. Also I want the post to match the session after submission, this removes that

Comment: @samswift if someone refreshes the page using the old post data which I think you're trying to prevent, the old $_POST['token'] will still contain the old value whereas the $_SESSION['token'] will contain a new token. EDIT* Ill add a function for this later when I have time btw

Comment: that still leaves the issue of the fact that if the old post token = 1234, the new session token could equal 2345, meaning the comparison would not work and resend the data on every subsequent resubmission

Comment: How does 1234 == 2345 return true? :/ especially if you create a larger random value the chances of them both being the exact same string or extremely unlikely

Comment: Because the post token (1234) !== the session token (2345), so the function in the way it should be, would return true